# Moral Luck and Complex Systems Theory

Tags: ethics, moral-agency, complexity

Is there any rigorous research done into links between Thomas Nagel's concept of 'moral luck,' and complex systems theory and/or game theory. Specifically, modeling ethical decision making in complex or epistemically constrained environments.

I work in a context with high degrees of ethnic conflict. Individuals and interest groups make decisions on resource allocation and security which are often subject to subconscious bias, paranoia, and a lack of verified information and small decisions may have complex and unpredictable outcomes either to perpetuate or deescalate ethnic violence.

I have been conducting a review of the literature but, have not found any rigorous analysis which links the two concepts.

*Nagel, Thomas, 1979, Mortal Questions, New York: Cambridge University Press; page reference is to the reprint of chapter 3 in Statman 1993b.
Williams, Bernard, 1981, Moral Luck: Philosophical Papers 1973–1980, Cambridge: Cambridge University Press.
–––, 1993, “Postscript”, in Moral Luck, D. Statman (ed.), Albany: State University of New York Press.*

Comment: Is this merely a reference request? As best I know (and for reasons I can imagine) the concept of 'moral luck' never really took off as a research topic, so I doubt there is much. Or are you looking for insights into the issue?

Comment: Thanks @TedWrigley that is a helpful point. I am not seeing much research on 'moral luck,' when I conduct my own search so, I am requesting assistance or direction on where to look and if it has ever been applied in an interdisciplinary manner to complex systems. To me at least, it had initially seemed like a logical direction to take the concept of moral luck in.

Comment: I see that, but the issue is that the 'problem' of moral luck isn't really coherent. There's a good analysis of its weaknesses over at [SEP](https://plato.stanford.edu/entries/moral-luck/#:~:text=As%20Nagel%20defines%20it%2C%20“Where,(Nagel%201979%2C%2059).) It seems more a question of how one might (externally) assess the morality of others, not how one might (internally) make moral decisions. That isn't of much interest to theorists.

Comment: I think you're right about the initial formulation of the concept @TedWrigley, that is a good point. Putting moral luck in the context of complex decision making, where not all variables are known (and not all unknowns are known), and where the actions will have 'complex' effects makes it more interesting (maybe). I think I was looking for how to weigh the moral risk or luck in internal decision making when a clear linear decision making process following traditional utilitarian or deontological isn't possible. Maybe, this has not been rigorously pursued in the research.

Comment: I'm curious what you mean by the phrase: "when a clear linear decision making process following traditional utilitarian or deontological isn't possible." (utilitarianism is a kind of deontology, incidentally; ethics is normally separated into deontology, consequentialism, virtue ethics, and pragmatism). Complex systems create problems for consequentialism, but not for the others, and it's always possible to make ethical choices even with restricted information.